# Redhat Linux DM-0 reported xfs in memory data corruption after it is cloned to run on another machine

Tags: linux, boot, raid, redhat-enterprise-linux, clone

I have Redhat Linux system running HA, with DRBD, and logical Raiding enabled on 4 drives.
Namely sda/sdb/sdc/sdd.

sda/sdb are the HA drives with XFS.

sdc/sdd are the OS drives with XFS.

I cloned the drives and installed them onto a new machine with a bootable stick. After the installation, I ran dmsetup ls, and everything is fine, and updated the raid uuids on grubs and mdadm confs.

The machine is able to boot up with no problems. After a couple days of running it, xfs corruption occurs. The machine boots into rescue mode.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhnMg.png)

What is causing this?

Comment: Solution to shut down HA before cloning. And xfs_ncheck/repair before cloning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need shutdown HA and clone using a bootable image. Be sure to xfs_ncheck/repair after duplicating the images on the drives.